# HTML email template (if / else Outlook or not) not working

Tags: html, email

I'm currently trying to build an if / else for my html email layout to include different table tags. This is what I'm trying:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<table class="content-table" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="45" align="center" border="0">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]> <!---->
<table class="content-table" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
<!-- <![endif]-->
</table>
```

So I'm trying to start my table with a different beginn tag if the mail is opened in outlook. But this is not working. Whats wrong?

This is not a duplicate!

Comment: where is the php for this? And probably a form if you're using one.

Comment: It's located on my Linux V-Server Ubuntu 16.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if an HTML email is being opened in Outlook 2007 or 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189685/how-can-i-detect-if-an-html-email-is-being-opened-in-outlook-2007-or-2010)

Comment: @IdontDownVote sorry but this isn't a duplicate. I've got my changes from there but it's not working like expected. Just to ask, is it possible to block you?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of how you show and hide in Outlook. If you're viewing this in Outlook, you'll see the word "Outlook". If you view it in a modern email client, you see the words "Modern Email".

https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/5hruzos5/1/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/0000ff/?text=Modern+Email" alt="Modern+Email" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/ff0000?text=Outlook" alt="" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Comment: OMFG thank you!  I thought I hated IE, I've been doing nothing but coding around Outlook for days.  Makes IE seem friendly and warm.